# jquery click event firing simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery code which handles some click events but i've ran into a problem where its firing both click events ive tried binding/unbinding them but not worked as i wanted it to. I've created a simplified version of it for demo.

```
jQuery('.tabs').click(function(e){
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});

// jQuery('close_slide').click(function()){
//    jQuery(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
// });

// Not part of Original question.
// But fixing the typos as they wony cause mention issue.
// Credits: @Jonas W.
jQuery('.close_slide').click(function() {
   jQuery(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

The close slide element is inside of tabs so when i click the close slide element it doesnt remove as expected/

Thanks

Comment: Correct ... typo Mistake is there

Comment: You probably will want to `stopPropagation` - https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: `close_slide` or `.close_slide` ?

Comment: As Amir said, your event is probably bubbling up to that class.

Comment: Im voting to reopen because even if there are typos they don't cause the problem described by the OP

Comment: @JonasW. I have updated question and have credited you for noticing typos are not real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just stop the events propagation:

```
jQuery('.close_slide').click(function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  jQuery(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: As an improvement, you can also use `.parents('.tabs')` instead of multiple `.parent()`